# How to find the random value for a particular string in an array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have a text file in the following format with more than 100 entries

```
Header Responses 
--- AMD 6001 ---
Sent Packet
FRO 101
A_TEST 5001
Status 0

--- AMD 6002 ---
Sent Packet
FRO 101
A_TEST 5002
Status 1
```

My requirement is to validate whether the value of 'Status' is 0, if so, proceed further to *fetch the random 'A_TEST' value*  from each entry. Could you please help me with an effective approach to  **find the 'A_Test' values in each entry**, because time taken for execution is more important due to large number entries.

I have written a code in following structure

```
set txtfile = fso.OpenTextFile("")
set content= txtfile.ReadAll
arrEntry = split (content,"--- AMD")
For num=1 to ubound(arrEntry)
    '2nd entry fails due to its entry status    
    If Instr(arrEntry(num),"Status 0") > 0 Then
        ' How to proceed further to get the value of 'A_TEST' from this array ???? 
    Else
        'Fail - Dont Proceed Further
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails, because

```
set content= txtfile.ReadAll
```

wrongly uses `Set` to assign a non-object (String) to a variable. Something like

```
  Dim sAll : sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\31429305.txt").ReadAll()
  Dim s
  For Each s In Split(sAll, "--- AMD")
      If InStr(s, "Status 0") Then
         WScript.Echo Split(s, vbCrLf)(3)
      End If
  Next
```

will 'work' if you are lucky (EOL marker is vbCrLf, A_TEST always in 4th line).

I'd use a RegExp, as in:

```
  Dim sAll : sAll     = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\31429305.txt").ReadAll()
  Dim rCut : Set rCut = New RegExp
  rCut.Global    = True
  rCut.Multiline = True
  rCut.Pattern   = "^A_TEST (\d+)\r$\n^Status 0\r$"
  Dim m
  For Each m In rCut.Execute(sAll)
      WScript.Echo m.Submatches(0)
  Next
```